# Why do I keep getting node_modules file changes showing up on Git without touching my code?

Tags: node-modules, diff, github-desktop

I've got a pretty simple repository made up of a frontend folder in which I have a react app, and a backend folder that is mostly empty for now.

Every few minutes, regardless of whether or not I make any changes to any files, some node_modules file will pop up in GitHub desktop showing a difference.

[screenshot of my github desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R623E.png)

Do I need to add node_modules to my .gitignore file?

This didn't happen before, I don't know what happened to trigger this. I add the changes because I assume it's an important node_modules update but then it happens again a few minutes later.

I'd like to understand why this is happening and how I can prevent it from happening as it makes my commit history impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to gitignore node modules like so...

```
/node_modules
```

Unless you have a specific reason to track changes to npm?
It's usually better to install fresh packages via `npm install` when setting up on a different enviroment/device.